# A comparison between the two images by Alheistogram

Tags: database, matlab, image-processing, histogram

My project is a query about the image and I am you first comparison between the two images by each image Histogram  If alike given by presents to me that the picture is similar, but the problem whenever he tells me Enter the two are not alike

```
A=imread('C:\Users\saba\Desktop\images\q4.jpg');%reading images as array to variable 'a'&'b' 
B = imread('C:\Users\saba\Desktop\images\q1.jpg');
j=rgb2gray(A);
i=rgb2gray(B);
subplot(2,2,1);imshow(A);
subplot(2,2,2);imshow(B);
subplot(2,2,3);imshow(j);
subplot(2,2,4);imshow(i);

if  histeq(j)==histeq(i)
   disp('The images are same')%output display 
else 
   disp('the images are not same') 
end
```

Comment: Are q4 and q1 the same image? Perhaps you need to find a measure of similarity instead of an exact match of histograms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to compare directly with the `==` operator the images would have to be the same images. If you are wanting to do this, you could just check if `i==j`, provided they are the same size.

As far as I know, there is no builtin function or toolbox which checks whether or not two images are similar. One rough method you could use is seeing how different the sums of the pixel values for each of the rows and the columns are:

```
maxColumnDifference = max(abs(sum(j, 1) - sum(i, 1)));
maxRowDifference = max(abs(sum(j, 2) - sum(i, 2)));
```

You could then have some tolerance which the sums must be within, should be a function of the size of the image. To give a standardised answer (0-255) of how different the row or the column is, just divide each of the sums by the number of pixels.

```
maxColumnDifference = max(abs(sum(j, 1)/size(j,1) - sum(i, 1)/size(i,1)));
maxRowDifference = max(abs(sum(j, 2)/size(j,2) - sum(i, 2)/size(i,2)));
```

You could then determine if they are similar with something like:

```
tolerance = 50;
if (maxRowDifference < tolerance) && (maxColumnDifference < tolerance)
    disp('Images are similarish');
else
    disp('Images are not similar enough for this poor tool to recognise');
end
```

Note that this is all speculation, not tested at all, and there is probably a better way of doing it.